# Highcharts - How would I use HTML input boxes to input the data for a Pie Chart?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, highcharts

Sorry, this is my first stackoverflow question so let me know if I've formatted this wrong.

I attempted to use `document.getElementById("id").value` in order to get the input value from the input box but I couldn't quite figure out how to make it work. I saw other answers making use of JSON or JQuery but I don't have much experience in those yet so if I could make this work without those(if possible) I'll take that option.
Any bits of code that are commented out are just me trying to get it to work.
(Sidenote: I know my HTML code might be a bit scuffed, that isn't a priority right now)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Pricer.ie</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="homepage.css"/>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/themes/gray.js"></script>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li class="logo">
                    <a href=""><img src="logopricer.png" alt="logo" id="logo" ></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="login.py" class="logintopright">Login</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <main>
            <figure class="highcharts-figure">
                <div id="container" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>
                <script>
                    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
                    var myChart = Highcharts.chart({
                        chart: {
                            renderTo: 'container',
                            type: 'pie',
                            events: {
                                load: function(event) {
                                    var chart = this,
                                        points = chart.series[0].points,
                                        len = points.length,
                                        total = 0,
                                        i = 0;

                                    for (; i < len; i++) {
                                        total += points[i].y;
                                    }

                                    chart.setTitle({
                                        text: '<span style="font-size: 13px">Current Price</small><br>'  + '<b>' + '€' + total.toFixed(2) + '</b>',
                                        align: 'center',
                                        verticalAlign: 'middle',
                                        y: -10,
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: 'Product Details'
                        },
                        tooltip: {
                            pointFormat: '<b>{point.percentage:.1f}</b>' + '<b>%</b>'
                        },
                        plotOptions: {
                            pie: {
                            allowPointSelect: true,
                            cursor: 'pointer',
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: true,
                                format: '{point.name}: €{point.y:.2f}'
                            }
                            }
                        },
                        series: [{
                            name: 'Total', [{
                                name: 'Profit Margin',
                                // y: document.getElementById('pcost').value
                                y : 0.29
                            }, {
                                name: 'Taxes',
                                // y: document.getElementById('taxes').value // external thing! database cuz tax changes depending on product
                                y : 4.25
                            }, {
                                name: 'Ebay Fees',
                                // y: document.getElementById('listfee').value
                                y : 3.93
                            }, {
                                name: 'Unit + Shipping Costs',
                                // y : document.getElementById('icost').value + document.getElementById('scost').value
                                y : 17.03  
                            }],
                            size: '60%',
                            innerSize: '70%',
                            showInLegend:true,
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: true
                            }
                        }]
                    },
                    )
                    }
                    )
                </script>
            </figure>
            <article>
                <form>
                    <label for="icost">Item Cost:</label>
                    <input type="number" id="icost" name="icost" step="0.01"><br><br>
                    <label for="scost">Shipping Cost:</label>
                    <input type="number" id="scost" name="scost" step="0.01"><br><br>     <!-- names and ids are incorrect just like this for now -->
                    <label for="pcost">Pickpack Cost:</label>
                    <input type="number" id="pcost" name="scost" step="0.01"><br><br>
                    <label for="taxes">Taxes:</label>
                    <input type="number" id="taxes" name="taxes" step="0.01"><br><br>     <!-- shouldnt exist as taxes is from database but sure look-->
                    <label for="listfee">Listing Fee:</label>
                    <input type="number" id="listfee" name="listfee"><br><br>
                    <button onclick="Function()">Save Changes</button>
                  </form>
            </article>
        </main>
        <footer>
        </footer>
    </body>
<html>
```

I would link to a **JSFiddle** but not sure how I would do that as my JS is currently embedded within my HTML lol. Thanks in advance to anyone that decides to give me a hand with this. Any advice with this is useful!

Comment: The solution to this is twofold: a) grab and process values from a form, either in real-time or after a button click b) update a live chart's data. Which one do you have trouble with, and what have you tried so far?

Comment: @ChrisG, hey, so I've tried processing values from my forms and tried to make it so when I click the button (after filling all fields) the function will run again but using the values I entered to build the pie chart. I kind of have trouble with both as it's not working at all! Although the chart works fine with predefined values, is there anyway for me to upload an image of how it works so far? Also keep in mind, I don't need it to update instantly after entering data, only after hitting 'Save Changes'.

Comment: Here's an Imgur of what it looks like: https://imgur.com/a/9kUqPeK

Comment: Can you add the code you've tried in your question?

Comment: @ChrisG sorry it's already in the question, I just commented it out, I'm sorry I just didn't know exactly what to do!

Comment: Ah; I missed that. It won't live update though, and you haven't implemented the button's onclick handler function. Do that, and call `myChart.series[0].setData([ ... ])` and pass the form values; that should work.

Comment: Here's my take: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/76fpvgnb/

Comment: @ChrisG thank you so much! That is more or less perfect for what I was looking to do :) The use of an array and then updating its contents was something I didn't think of doing! I guess Highcharts needs the data to be in a certain format and what I originally did didn't suit it. One last question, is there any way for me to use the button to update the chart with the data?

Comment: @ChrisG also create an answer so I can flag it as my accepted answer :)

Comment: The button in my fiddle already updates the chart, didn't you try it? Change any of the numbers and click "Save Changes", and the chart will update accordingly. It didn't work the way you tried because a) the inputs were blank initially b) you need to turn the value into a number first, or highcharts ignores it

Comment: sorry I should have said I tried it there and it works so thank you for that also! And okay that's interesting.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get data and put them in a format required by Highcharts. Simple example below:

```
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var data = [
        parseInt(document.getElementById('data1').value),
        parseInt(document.getElementById('data2').value)
    ];

    Highcharts.chart('container', {
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            data
        }]
    });
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/dyp5208b/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pie.data

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! It looks like it should work for my situation however I think I might use Chris answer from above as it's more familiar to me. Thank you for taking the time to help me out tho :) I'm gonna read up on parseInt().